# Monitoring Excel's Edit Mode Via NativeWindow Subclassing Not Working In Excel DNA

Tags: c#, excel, winapi, excel-dna

Excel enters "Edit Mode" when a user performs one of the following actions: double clicks a cell, starts typing over it, keys F2, or clicks into the formula bar. When "Edit Mode" is activated, Excel opens a specific window, class name == "EXCEL6". I am trying to detect this programmatically by subclassing the "EXCEL6" window using my `ExcelEditModeMonitor` class, but the `WndProc` override never seems to be invoked.

Any ideas on why this is?

Test Code:

```
public sealed class ExcelDnaAddIn : IExcelAddIn
{
    ExcelEditModeMonitor _editModeMonitor; 
    public void AutoOpen()
    {
        _editModeMonitor = new ExcelEditModeMonitor(ExcelDnaUtil.Application); 
        _editModeMonitor.EditModeActivate += OnExcelEditModeActivate; 
        _editModeMonitor.EditModeDeactivate += OnExcelEditModeDeactivate; 
    }
    
    public void AutoClose()
    {
        _editModeMonitor.Dispose(); 
    }
    
    private void OnExcelEditModeActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Editor Active!");
    }

    private void OnExcelEditModeDeactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Editor Inactive!");
    }
}
```

Class is below for reference:

```
public sealed class ExcelEditModeMonitor : NativeWindow, IDisposable
{
    public enum ExcelEditWindowState
    {
        InActive = 0, 
        Active = 1
    }

    private class Win32
    {
        public enum WM
        {
            WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 0x0047,
            WM_STYLECHANGED = 0x007D,
            WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007,
            WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static public extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hChild, string strClassName, string strName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static public extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static public extern bool IsWindowEnabled(IntPtr hWnd);
    }

    private bool _inCellDirectEditEnabled = false;
    private ExcelEditWindowState _editWindowState = ExcelEditWindowState.InActive;

    private event EventHandler _editModeActivate;
    private event EventHandler _editModeDeactivate;

    private long _disposedCount = 0;

    public event EventHandler EditModeActivate
    {
        add
        {
            _editModeActivate += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _editModeActivate -= value;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler EditModeDeactivate
    {
        add
        {
            _editModeDeactivate += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _editModeDeactivate -= value;
        }
    }

    public ExcelEditWindowState EditWindowState => _editWindowState;


    public ExcelEditModeMonitor(dynamic excelApp)
    {
        if (excelApp == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(excelApp));

        IntPtr editorWindowHwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        _inCellDirectEditEnabled = excelApp.EditDirectlyInCell;
        if (!_inCellDirectEditEnabled)
        {
            editorWindowHwnd = Win32.FindWindowEx(new IntPtr(excelApp.Hwnd), IntPtr.Zero, "EXCEL<", String.Empty);
            if (editorWindowHwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SetupWindowMonitoring(editorWindowHwnd);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            editorWindowHwnd = FindEditorHandle(excelApp.Hwnd, "XLDESK", "EXCEL6");
            if (editorWindowHwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SetupWindowMonitoring(editorWindowHwnd);
                return;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Excel editor window not found!");
    }

    private IntPtr FindEditorHandle(int excelAppHwnd, string mainWindowName, string editorWindowName)
    {
        IntPtr workbookContainer = Win32.FindWindowEx(new IntPtr(excelAppHwnd), IntPtr.Zero, mainWindowName, String.Empty);
        IntPtr editWindow = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (workbookContainer != IntPtr.Zero)
        {   
            editWindow = Win32.FindWindowEx(workbookContainer, IntPtr.Zero, editorWindowName, String.Empty);
        }

        return editWindow;
    }

    private void SetupWindowMonitoring(IntPtr editorWindow)
    {
        AssignHandle(editorWindow);
        CheckWindowState();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (Interlocked.Read(ref _disposedCount) > 0)
            return;

        if (disposing) // Clean up managed state 
        {
            EditModeActivate -= _editModeActivate;
            EditModeDeactivate -= _editModeDeactivate;
            _editModeActivate = null;
            _editModeDeactivate = null; 
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        ReleaseHandle();
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _disposedCount);
    }

    ~ExcelEditModeMonitor()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Observe the window state changes, visibility, enabled state, etc.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            // win32 message if style of the targetwindow has changed by any Win32 API call
            // WS_VISIBLE flag or any other
            case (int)Win32.WM.WM_STYLECHANGED:
                CheckWindowState();
                break;

            // win32 message if position of the targetwindow has changed by SetWindowPos
            // API call SWP_SHOWWINDOW for instance
            case (int)Win32.WM.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
                CheckWindowState();
                break;

            case (int)Win32.WM.WM_SETFOCUS:
                CheckWindowState(true);
                break;

            case (int)Win32.WM.WM_KILLFOCUS:
                CheckWindowState(false);
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check style/pos state change.
    /// <param name="isEnabled">
    /// This parameter only takes effect if _inCellDirectEditEnabled == true for 
    /// the excel application.
    /// </param>
    /// </summary>
    private void CheckWindowState(bool isEnabled = false)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_inCellDirectEditEnabled && isEnabled)
            {
                if (_editWindowState == ExcelEditWindowState.InActive)
                {
                    _editWindowState = ExcelEditWindowState.Active;
                    RaiseExcelEditWindowStateChangedEvent(_editModeActivate, new object[] { this, EventArgs.Empty });
                }
            }
            else if (!_inCellDirectEditEnabled && !isEnabled)
            {
                if (_editWindowState == ExcelEditWindowState.Active)
                {
                    _editWindowState = ExcelEditWindowState.InActive;
                    RaiseExcelEditWindowStateChangedEvent(_editModeDeactivate, new object[] { this, EventArgs.Empty });
                }
            }
            else if (Win32.IsWindowVisible(this.Handle) && Win32.IsWindowEnabled(this.Handle))
            {
                if (_editWindowState == ExcelEditWindowState.InActive)
                {
                    _editWindowState = ExcelEditWindowState.Active;
                    RaiseExcelEditWindowStateChangedEvent(_editModeActivate, new object[] { this, EventArgs.Empty });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (_editWindowState == ExcelEditWindowState.Active)
                {
                    _editWindowState = ExcelEditWindowState.InActive;
                    RaiseExcelEditWindowStateChangedEvent(_editModeDeactivate, new object[] { this, EventArgs.Empty });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void RaiseExcelEditWindowStateChangedEvent(Delegate eventHandler, object[] args)
    {
        if (eventHandler == null)
            return;

        Delegate[] delegates = eventHandler.GetInvocationList();
        if (delegates == null)
            return; 

        foreach (var del in delegates)
        {
            try
            {
                del.DynamicInvoke(args);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to monitor this event, going through an official programming interface, that doesn't break when the Excel team decides to rename the window class to "GETOFFMYLAWN".

Comment: @IInspectable I wish there was a way to do so through Excel's API, but there isn't. There is only one other way (also not through any existing Excel API) using the `XLCALL32.DLL` function `LPenHelper`, but then I would have to constantly poll Excel calling that function and inspecting its value which I would rather not do. If you know  of any other way, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't been able to figure out why the `WndProc` override isn't being invoked. Aside from that, as [@IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) pointed out, there is always a possibility that the Excel development team could change the class name of the Editor window, which would render the code useless anyway.

Through a great deal of research, I [discovered a way to reliably detect Excel's edit mode](https://dev.to/sharpcells/a-novel-method-to-monitor-excels-edit-mode-8hh) (without relying on the WinAPI and subclassing) using the undocumented function `LPenHelper` found in the the Excel SDK. By periodically calling this function and inspecting inspecting its return value, one can raise an event if the mode changed.

**Background** 
The `LPenHelper` function is defined in the XLCALL32.h header file and implemented in the XLCALL32.DLL. The XLCALL32.h defines many important constants, data types, structs, and functions that are accessible via the Excel SDK, but for monitoring Excel's Edit mode, we only need to define following:

```
private const int xlSpecial = 0x4000;
private const int xlGetFmlaInfo = (14 | xlSpecial);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct FmlaInfo
{
    public int wPointMode;  // current edit mode.  0 => rest of struct undefined
    public int cch;         // count of characters in formula
    public IntPtr lpch;     // pointer to formula characters.  READ ONLY!!!
    public int ichFirst;    // char offset to start of selection
    public int ichLast;     // char offset to end of selection (may be > cch)
    public int ichCaret;    // char offset to blinking caret
}

[DllImport("XLCALL32.DLL")]
private static extern int LPenHelper(int wCode, ref FmlaInfo fmlaInfo);

/// <summary>
/// Represents the the current cell editing mode displayed on the left side of 
/// Excel's status bar.
/// </summary> 
public enum xlEditMode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This value is does not correlate with an actual Excel cell edit mode,
    /// but is used as a return value when an exception occurs while attempting
    /// to poll the current state.
    /// </summary> 
    Undefined = -1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the default state. 
    /// </summary> 
    Ready = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates when a cell is selected and typing has begun, or when F2 is keyed 
    /// twice.
    /// </summary> 
    Enter = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates in-cell editing, which occurs as a result of double clicking a
    /// cell, keying F2 to enter data. 
    /// </summary> 
    Edit = 2,

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates in-cell formula selection mode, which occurs as a result of entering
    /// a formula, and clicking the cells/ranges to include in that formula.
    /// </summary> 
    Point = 4
}
```

The actual monitoring just consists of periodically polling Excel on the `ThreadPool` and raising an event if a state change is detected. I dislike polling, but I really don't see any other option.

```
private Timer _timer;
private const int PollingFrequency = 10; // milliseconds
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _internalTokenSource;
private readonly CancellationToken _internalToken;
private readonly CancellationToken _externalToken;
private xlEditMode _lastEditMode = xlEditMode.Ready;
private xlEditMode _currentEditMode = xlEditMode.Ready;

public xlEditMode LastEditMode => _lastEditMode;
public xlEditMode CurrentEditMode => _currentEditMode;

public event EventHandler<ExcelEditModeMonitorEventArgs> EditModeChange; 

public ExcelEditModeMonitor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _internalTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _internalToken = _internalTokenSource.Token; 
    _externalToken = cancellationToken;
    
    // run the timer every 10 milliseconds
   _timer = new Timer(_timer_Elapsed, null, 0, PollingFrequency);
}

private void _timer_Elapsed(object state)
{
    if (_externalToken.IsCancellationRequested || _internalToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        return; // stop the timer
    }

    _lastEditMode = _currentEditMode; 
    _currentEditMode = GetEditMode();

    if(_lastEditMode != _currentEditMode)
    {
        EditModeChange?.Invoke(this, new ExcelEditModeMonitorEventArgs(_lastEditMode, _currentEditMode));
    }
}

private xlEditMode GetEditMode()
{
    try
    {
        FmlaInfo fmlaInfo = new FmlaInfo();
        int retVal = LPenHelper(xlGetFmlaInfo, ref fmlaInfo);
        if (retVal != 0)
        {
            return xlEditMode.Undefined;
        }

        return (xlEditMode)fmlaInfo.wPointMode;
    }
    catch
    {
        return xlEditMode.Undefined;
    }
}
```

**Testing** 
Then to wire it all up we can do the following:

```
public sealed class ExcelDnaAddIn : IExcelAddIn
{
    CancellationTokenSource _globalCancellationTokenSource; 
    ExcelEditModeMonitor _editModeMonitor; 
    public void AutoOpen()
    {
        _globalCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); 
        _editModeMonitor = new ExcelEditModeMonitor(_globalCancellationTokenSource); 
        _editModeMonitor.EditModeChange += OnEditModeChange; 
    }
    
    public void AutoClose()
    {
        _editModeMonitor.Dispose(); 
    }
    
    private void OnExcelEditModeChange(object sender, ExcelEditModeMonitorEventArgs e)
    {
        var last = Enum.GetName(typeof(ExcelEditModeMonitor.xlEditMode), e.LastEditMode);
        var current = Enum.GetName(typeof(ExcelEditModeMonitor.xlEditMode), e.CurrentEditMode);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Excel Edit Mode Changed From {last} to {current}");
    }
}
```

Below is the full code for reference:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

/// <summary>
/// Represents the "cell edit Mode" of Excel by periodically polling
/// its state via the XLCALL32.dll function "LPenHelper" and inspecting
/// its return value. 
/// </summary>
public sealed class ExcelEditModeMonitor: IDisposable
{
    // Constants, struct, and LPenHelper are all defined in the XLCALL32.h file
    private const int xlSpecial = 0x4000;
    private const int xlGetFmlaInfo = (14 | xlSpecial);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct FmlaInfo
    {
        public int wPointMode;  // current edit mode.  0 => rest of struct undefined
        public int cch;         // count of characters in formula
        public IntPtr lpch;     // pointer to formula characters.  READ ONLY!!!
        public int ichFirst;    // char offset to start of selection
        public int ichLast;     // char offset to end of selection (may be > cch)
        public int ichCaret;    // char offset to blinking caret
    }

    [DllImport("XLCALL32.DLL")]
    private static extern int LPenHelper(int wCode, ref FmlaInfo fmlaInfo);

    private Timer _timer;
    private long _disposedCount = 0;
    private const int PollingFrequency = 10; // milliseconds
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _internalTokenSource;
    private readonly CancellationToken _internalToken;
    private readonly CancellationToken _externalToken;
    private xlEditMode _lastEditMode = xlEditMode.Ready;
    private xlEditMode _currentEditMode = xlEditMode.Ready;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the the current cell editing mode displayed on the left side of 
    /// Excel's status bar.
    /// </summary> 
    public enum xlEditMode
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This value is does not correlate with an actual Excel cell edit mode,
        /// but is used as a return value when an exception occurs while attempting
        /// to poll the current state.
        /// </summary> 
        Undefined = -1,

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents the default state. 
        /// </summary> 
        Ready = 0,

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates when a cell is selected and typing has begun, or when F2 is keyed 
        /// twice.
        /// </summary> 
        Enter = 1,

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates in-cell editing, which occurs as a result of double clicking a
        /// cell, keying F2 to enter data. 
        /// </summary> 
        Edit = 2,

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates in-cell formula selection mode, which occurs as a result of entering
        /// a formula, and clicking the cells/ranges to include in that formula.
        /// </summary> 
        Point = 4
    }

    public xlEditMode LastEditMode => _lastEditMode;
    public xlEditMode CurrentEditMode => _currentEditMode;

    public event EventHandler<ExcelEditModeMonitorEventArgs> EditModeChange; 

    public ExcelEditModeMonitor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _internalTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _internalToken = _internalTokenSource.Token; 
        _externalToken = cancellationToken;

       _timer = new Timer(_timer_Elapsed, null, 0, PollingFrequency);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // don't dispose more than once
        if (Interlocked.Read(ref _disposedCount) > 0)
            return;

        _internalTokenSource.Cancel(); 
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        _timer.Dispose();
        EditModeChange = null; 

        Interlocked.Increment(ref _disposedCount);
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object state)
    {
        if (_externalToken.IsCancellationRequested || _internalToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            return; 
        }

        _lastEditMode = _currentEditMode; 
        _currentEditMode = GetEditMode();

        if(_lastEditMode != _currentEditMode)
        {
            EditModeChange?.Invoke(this, new ExcelEditModeMonitorEventArgs(_lastEditMode, _currentEditMode));
        }
    }

    private xlEditMode GetEditMode()
    {
        try
        {
            FmlaInfo fmlaInfo = new FmlaInfo();
            int retVal = LPenHelper(xlGetFmlaInfo, ref fmlaInfo);
            if (retVal != 0)
            {
                return xlEditMode.Undefined;
            }

            return (xlEditMode)fmlaInfo.wPointMode;
        }
        catch
        {
            return xlEditMode.Undefined;
        }
    }
}

public sealed class ExcelEditModeMonitorEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ExcelEditModeMonitor.xlEditMode LastEditMode { get; set; }
    public ExcelEditModeMonitor.xlEditMode CurrentEditMode { get; set; }

    public ExcelEditModeMonitorEventArgs(ExcelEditModeMonitor.xlEditMode lastEditMode, ExcelEditModeMonitor.xlEditMode currentEditMode)
    {
        LastEditMode = lastEditMode;
        CurrentEditMode = currentEditMode;
    }
}
```

**Edit** 
Apparently Excel tends to crash intermittently when calling `LPenHelper` from any thread other than Excel's main UI thread. Based on the issue discussed in [ExcelDna.Intellisense Issue #87](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/IntelliSense/issues/87), I implemented some synchronization to prevent that. I also decorated the `GetEditMode` function with the [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute. See revised code below.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

/// <summary>
/// Represents the "cell edit Mode" of Excel by periodically polling
/// its state via the XLCALL32.dll function "LPenHelper" and inspecting
/// its return value. 
/// </summary>
public sealed class ExcelEditModeMonitor: IDisposable
{
    // Constants, struct, and LPenHelper are all defined in the XLCALL32.h file
    private const int xlSpecial = 0x4000;
    private const int xlGetFmlaInfo = (14 | xlSpecial);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct FmlaInfo
    {
        public int wPointMode;  // current edit mode.  0 => rest of struct undefined
        public int cch;         // count of characters in formula
        public IntPtr lpch;     // pointer to formula characters.  READ ONLY!!!
        public int ichFirst;    // char offset to start of selection
        public int ichLast;     // char offset to end of selection (may be > cch)
        public int ichCaret;    // char offset to blinking caret
    }

    [DllImport("XLCALL32.DLL")]
    private static extern int LPenHelper(int wCode, ref FmlaInfo fmlaInfo);

    private readonly WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext _excelMainThreadSyncContext;
    private System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private long _disposedCount = 0;
    private const int PollingFrequency = 10; // milliseconds
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _internalTokenSource;
    private readonly CancellationToken _internalToken;
    private readonly CancellationToken _externalToken;
    private xlEditMode _lastEditMode = xlEditMode.Ready;
    private xlEditMode _currentEditMode = xlEditMode.Ready;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the the current cell editing mode displayed on the left side of 
    /// Excel's status bar.
    /// </summary> 
    public enum xlEditMode
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This value is does not correlate with an actual Excel cell edit mode,
        /// but is used as a return value when an exception occurs while attempting
        /// to poll the current state.
        /// </summary> 
        Undefined = -1,

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents the default state. 
        /// </summary> 
        Ready = 0,

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates when a cell is selected and typing has begun, or when F2 is keyed 
        /// twice.
        /// </summary> 
        Enter = 1,

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates in-cell editing, which occurs as a result of double clicking a
        /// cell, keying F2 to enter data. 
        /// </summary> 
        Edit = 2,

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates in-cell formula selection mode, which occurs as a result of entering
        /// a formula, and clicking the cells/ranges to include in that formula.
        /// </summary> 
        Point = 4
    }

    public xlEditMode LastEditMode => _lastEditMode;
    public xlEditMode CurrentEditMode => _currentEditMode;

    public event EventHandler<ExcelEditModeMonitorEventArgs> EditModeChange; 

    public ExcelEditModeMonitor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _excelMainThreadSyncContext = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext();
        _internalTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _internalToken = _internalTokenSource.Token; 
        _externalToken = cancellationToken;

       _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_timer_Elapsed, null, 0, PollingFrequency);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // don't dispose more than once
        if (Interlocked.Read(ref _disposedCount) > 0)
            return;

        _internalTokenSource.Cancel(); 
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        _timer.Dispose();
        _excelMainThreadSyncContext.Dispose();
        EditModeChange = null; 

        Interlocked.Increment(ref _disposedCount);
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object state)
    {
        if (_externalToken.IsCancellationRequested || _internalToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            return; 
        }

        // Switches Excel's Main UI thread, and updates state
        _excelMainThreadSyncContext.Post(_ =>
        {
            _lastEditMode = _currentEditMode;
            _currentEditMode = GetEditMode();
            
            if(_lastEditMode != _currentEditMode)
            {
                EditModeChange?.Invoke(this, new ExcelEditModeMonitorEventArgs(_lastEditMode, _currentEditMode));
            }
        }, null);
    }
    
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    private xlEditMode GetEditMode()
    {
        try
        {
            FmlaInfo fmlaInfo = new FmlaInfo();
            int retVal = LPenHelper(xlGetFmlaInfo, ref fmlaInfo);
            if (retVal != 0)
            {
                return xlEditMode.Undefined;
            }

            return (xlEditMode)fmlaInfo.wPointMode;
        }
        catch
        {
            return xlEditMode.Undefined;
        }
    }
}

public sealed class ExcelEditModeMonitorEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ExcelEditModeMonitor.xlEditMode LastEditMode { get; set; }
    public ExcelEditModeMonitor.xlEditMode CurrentEditMode { get; set; }

    public ExcelEditModeMonitorEventArgs(ExcelEditModeMonitor.xlEditMode lastEditMode, ExcelEditModeMonitor.xlEditMode currentEditMode)
    {
        LastEditMode = lastEditMode;
        CurrentEditMode = currentEditMode;
    }
}
```